# Promise then and catch in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, promise

I'm having a problem with my nodejs server.

What I want is if an email exists in my db, I want to send an email to that address but if not, I want to send and error message to the client.

I have this controller:

```
reset(req, res) {
   return  this.service.getByEmail(req.body.email)
      .then(this.mapper.outputEmail.bind(this.mapper))
      .then(res.json.bind(res)).catch(res.send.bind(res));
  }
```

I send the email in a post method. I use a service that calls my db looking for that email and I have this mapper:

```
 outputEmail(outputEmail){
      return {
      email: outputEmail.email
    };
  }
```

My service:

```
getByEmail(correo) {
    return this.db.find({
      where: { email: correo }
    });
  }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to control if i get an empty json object.. If i send a post with an email that it doesnt exist i get a `{}` response, but if i send an exist email i get {email: erwrr@gmail.com}.

What i want is if i get an empty json, I just want to return an error saying that email doesnt exist, but if the query in the db gets a real email I want to continue executing another method that to send an email to that address.

Comment: You can throw exceptions inside of your services and these exceptions will be picked up by the catch block. This breaks the chain of execution of chained thens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to determine if there is an email field on your JSON object. Just do:

```
outputEmail(outputEmail){
    if(outputEmail.email){
        return {
            email: outputEmail.email
        };
    }else{
        throw new Error("No email found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank you!